# ArrayList for show products not work secondly

Tags: android, arraylist

i have two intent city and product.first app open city intent show and user select city . now city pass to product intent for show products.
I use array list for fetching data from php api and show to user in product intent:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> getDatalist;
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            prdArray = obj.getJSONArray("prd");
                            for(int aind = 0 ; aind < 2; aind++) {
                                final JSONObject do_id = prdArray.getJSONObject(aind);
                                String email = do_id.getString("email");
                                String phone = do_id.getString("phone");

                                HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("KEY_EMAIL",email);
                                map.put("KEY_PHONE",phone);
                                getDatalist.add(map);

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```

anything is OK now.Nut i have a bottom for change city when user click it . city Intent show and after city changed he coma back to product intent.but now products not show :(

```
    Button cityChange=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cityChange);
    cityChange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cityChangeIntent = new Intent(home.this,city.class);
            cityChangeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(cityChangeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Recycleviewadapter:

```
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element

    if (holder instanceof ViewHolderRow) {
        HashMap<String,String> map = mDataset.get(position);

        ViewHolderRow userViewHolder = (ViewHolderRow) holder;

        userViewHolder.txtEmail.setText(map.get("KEY_EMAIL"));
        userViewHolder.txtPhone.setText(map.get("KEY_PHONE"));

       .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop like this

```
for(int aind = 0 ; aind < prdArray.size; aind++) {
 //your code
}
```